# Finite concurrent API get requests via HttpClient

Tags: .net, concurrency, httpclient

I've deliberated on whether to include the code I've tried to date, but I think it's going to be easier to ask this from a blank slate given how many possible approaches there are. I'm a hobby coder and my knowledge of APIs/HttpClient is a bit limited.

I'm trying to write a wrapper for downloading strings (xml/json) and files (images/videos) from a third-party API. This API grants users a varying number of threads (in my case - 7).

You send the full request via the URL, an example being (annonymised):

https://www.3rdPartyApi.fr/api2/ssinfraInfos.php?devid=xxx&devpassword=yyy&softname=zzz&output=xml

It then returns and xml or json.

The question is, what is the best approach to maximise download speeds via using all threads?

I followed the guidance [here](https://makolyte.com/csharp-how-to-make-concurrent-requests-with-httpclient/), but the download times were exactly the same when using a concurrency of 1 as compared to 7. I'm processing around 1000 requests - both took around 11 seconds.

My reading has led me to different approaches, using SemaphoreSlim, Parallel task libraries and Parrallel.ForEach. I've messed around with all of them and just gotten the same results.

I'm afraid building my own API on localhost is a bit beyond me, so have no way to rule out the 3rd party server (although I have no reason to disbelieve that 7 threads should be quicker than 1).

Can anyone provide a germane piece of code showing how to achieve this? Thanks